# Масштабируемая сетка из шестигранников

Tags: css, html5, css3, анимация, svg

Я загрузил из Интернета  несколько изображений на мой сайт . Можно ли придать всем этим образам  **шестигранную форму** в `responsive grid`?

```
<div>
    <img src="link" class="Image">
</div>

<div>
    <img src="link" class="Image">
</div>
...
```

Я нашел несколько способов сделать это, но мне необходимо заполнить `src` изображения в коде CSS.  Это не подходит мне, потому что сайт загружает  случайные изображения из интернета с `jQuery`, поэтому я не могу их использовать как фоновые изображения.

Я собираюсь поддерживать WebKit браузеры, Firefox, IE8 было бы хорошо, но не нужно - и мобильные браузеры

Моя попытка здесь: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8f5m5wv0/)

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Responsive grid of hexagons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26114920/7394871) от участника  [@Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4073992/stefan).</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Здесь [demo](http://web-tiki.github.io/responsive-grid-of-hexagons/) и репозиторий для [responsive grid of hexagons](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons).  **Код здесь не поддерживается.**  Он был перемещен в `GitHub` и сильно улучшены  комментарии, вопрос отчетности и взносы должны быть сделаны [туда](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот метод использует:

- `<img>` тег
- неупорядоченный список: каждый шестиугольник содержится в теге `<li>`
  и теге `<a>`
- Использование `transform rotate`и `skew`, чтобы сделать шестигранные
  формы
- `overflow:hidden;`
- дочерние элементы `nth-child()` заполняют  шестигранник в качестве
  `pattern`

И еще, чтобы создать **шестигранную сетку** с тегом `<IMG>`.

### **Характеристики шестигранной сетки :**

- Сетка будет реагировать на изменение процентов
  ширины. Шестиугольники поддерживают своё соотношение сторон в
  соответствии с приемом [padding-bottom technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div) и изображения
  изменяют размер, чтобы соответствовать форме шестиугольника.
- `hover` **эффект поверх шестиугольников:** текст скользит  с
  прозрачным наложением над изображением.
- Каждый шестиугольник сохраняет свои границы: эффект `hover` (или
  событие `click` ) для каждого шестиугольника срабатывает только
  внутри реальной фигуры.

### Полный код

Следующий фрагмент кода не является последней версией сетки. [GitHub repo](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons) сохраняется и до настоящего времени. Вопросы и вклады могут быть сделаны там.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
    background: rgb(123, 158, 158);
}

#hexGrid {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0.707% 0;
}

#hexGrid:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.hex {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.hex * {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
}

.hexIn {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
        -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
            transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* HEX CONTENT */

.hex img {
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hex h1, .hex p {
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 5%;
    background-color: #008080;
    background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.8);
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
            transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
}

.hex h1 {
    bottom: 110%;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-top: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.hex h1:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.hex p {
    padding-top: 50%;
    top: 110%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}


/* HOVER EFFECT  */

.hexIn:hover h1 {
    bottom: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.hexIn:hover p {
    top: 50%;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

/* SPACING AND SIZING */

@media (min-width:1201px) {
    .hex {
        width: 19.2%; /* = (100-4) / 5 */
        padding-bottom: 22.170%; /* =  width / sin(60deg) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+7),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+8),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+9) {
        margin-top: -4.676%;
        margin-bottom: -4.676%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(9n+7):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(9n+8):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(9n+9):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+6) {
        margin-left: 0.5%;
        clear: left;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+10) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+2),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+ 7) {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(9n+3),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+4),
    .hex:nth-child(9n+8) {
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
    .hex {
        width: 24.25%; /* = (100-3) / 4 */
        padding-bottom: 28.001%; /* =  width / sin(60deg) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5),
    .hex:nth-child(7n+6),
    .hex:nth-child(7n+7) {
        margin-top: -6.134%;
        margin-bottom: -6.134%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(7n+6):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(7n+7):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+2),
    .hex:nth-child(7n+6) {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+3) {
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+8) {
        clear: left;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(7n+5) {
        clear: left;
        margin-left: 0.5%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
    .hex {
        width: 32.666%; /* = (100-2) / 3 */
        padding-bottom: 37.720%; /* =  width / sin(60) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4),
    .hex:nth-child(5n+5) {
        margin-top: -8.564%;
        margin-bottom: -8.564%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4):last-child,
    .hex:nth-child(5n+5):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+4) {
        margin-right: 1%;
        margin-left: 0.5%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+2) {
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(5n+6) {
        clear: left;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .hex {
        width: 49.5%; /* = (100-1) / 2 */
        padding-bottom: 57.158%; /* =  width / sin(60) */
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-top: -13.423%;
        margin-bottom: -13.423%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
            -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
                transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+3):last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-left: 0.5%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+2) {
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
    .hex:nth-child(3n+4) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,800italic,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,300,200,100,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<ul id="hexGrid">
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7163/6822904141_50277565c3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3771/13199704015_72aa535bd7.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2878/10944255073_973d2cd25c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2878/10944255073_973d2cd25c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6217/6216951796_e50778255c.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7163/6822904141_50277565c3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3771/13199704015_72aa535bd7.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6139/5986939269_10721b8017.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3165/5733278274_2626612c70.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7163/6822904141_50277565c3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3771/13199704015_72aa535bd7.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <img src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>This is a title</h1>
      <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Изменение количества шестиугольников в ряду

Сетка адаптирует количество шестиугольников в ряду в зависимости от ширины окна просмотра. С пятью шестиугольниками на экранах шире, чем 1200px, и до 2-х на экранах уже, чем 600px.

Если вам не нужны `media queries`, но просто хотите изменить количество шестиугольников в строке, то вы можете сохранить CSS из соответствующего `media queries` и затем удалить ненужные из них.

Для получения дополнительных настроек см. [sizing and spacing of hexagons](https://github.com/web-tiki/responsive-grid-of-hexagons#spacing-and-sizing-calculations).

### Demos

Для получения списка всех демок, посмотрите эту коллекцию на codepen: [Responsive grids of hexagons](http://codepen.io/collection/npgxpm/)  с разным числом шестиугольников в каждом ряду, а также опции центрирования и многое другое ...

Вот оригинал [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/HhCyd) с `.pusher` элементом, чтобы сделать неправильную сетку из шестиугольников. `.pusher` элемент используется для создания "дыр" в сетке с пустыми шестиугольниками.

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26116497/7394871) от участника  [@иweb-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>